# Memory leak in IE8?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8

http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/SyHFR/

Sorry for the messy code - I have modified a script not chosen by me and originally from Dynamic Drive - it is used by someone I am helping and rather that rewriting the whole thing from scratch, I agreed to the feature creep. The intended changes was to add a repeat after and a delay by vars

Now I just want to understand where there could be a problem - I changed the code from using a date object every second to use it only when initialising.

The code

```
cdtime.prototype.updateTime=function(){
  var thisobj=this;
  this.currentTime+=1000; // one second
  setTimeout(function(){thisobj.updateTime()}, 1000) //update time every second
}
```

gives a

*Message: 'thisobj' is null or not an object*

after about 9 hours in IE8 on XP

I am running it myself now on another box over the weekend, but was wondering if someone could enlighten me as to what could be the issue with IE.

**HMM - pasting the function right now, I see the settimeout is inside a prototype - that suddenly does not look right.**

Please also do feel free to point me to a better counter that can do what this one is doing, e.g. start after a delay, repeat after a given time and have more than one counter on the page styled by CSS.

UPDATE

Trying the setInterval makes the whole coundown very choppy
http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/z2AQF/

Comment: Hi, what do you actually want to create by modifying the code? That might help to answer.

Comment: Just added the delay and the repeat

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but isn't creating that anonymous function to setTimeout that references thisobj, is causing that function to not be eligible for gc?

Comment: Possibly - if you can think of a better way to implement it (and I mean a BETTER way - you answer was not a better way in my opinion)

Comment: I have deleted my answer here's the updated fiddle, maybe it will point you/others to the better solution http://jsfiddle.net/liviu/6z4XL/4/

Comment: @Liviu - did you try to leave your fiddle running for a little while? It is VERY flaky.

Comment: I let it run for about 3h ... didn't see a problem or memory increase

Comment: I ran it for a little while in FF, it is completely random the time it counts down and whether or not is shows the waiting message

Comment: Thanks - I am no longer interested in the answer since I rewrote the whole thing. I just like to have 100% if possible :)

Answer (score 1):

If it is really a memory leak, try clearing the `thisobj` variable from the function passed to `setTimeout`:

```
cdtime.prototype.updateTime = function () {
    var thisobj=this;
    this.currentTime+=1000; // one second
    setTimeout(function () {
        thisobj.updateTime();
        thisobj = null;
    }, 1000); //update time every second
};
```

If you look closer, this function is basically an interval, so the following would be more optimized since it does not stack up on old functions:

```
cdtime.prototype.updateTime = function () {
    var thisobj = this;
    setInterval(function () {
        thisobj.currentTime += 1000;
    }, 1000);
};
```

Comment: Using interval makes the counter extremely choppy and inaccurate

Comment: I am trying to do a delete thisobj. I do not quite understand that I can do that.

Comment: `delete thisobj` may return `true` even if nothing happened. `delete thisobj` won't work since it was declared using `var`. The correct way to clear the reference is by setting it to `null`.

Comment: Thanks - Do you have some documentation on that?

Comment: Documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Special/delete. I've just looked at the code and it's really bad written code. Try rewriting it, take the requirements out of it and build new code on that. Perhaps you should totally drop that and try jQuery.

Comment: I could rewrite it. I fail to see any requirement that would be helped using jQuery though

Comment: Well, you want to insert the date in some element. jQuery can be used for that. Furthermore, I don't consider Dynamic Drive a source of well-written JS. Writing a countdown timer isn't that difficult, but if you don't have time for it, why not use a jQuery plugin like [this one](http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html)?

Comment: I completely agree on the DD - I am not the originator of this script, nor the person who chose to use it - but apart from $(selector).html(sometime) I do not see where jQuery is needed.